AWS EC2 - enX0: Could not set DHCPv4 address: Connection timed out
After my EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2023) has been running for several hours (around 5-8 hours), it suddenly fails with an "Instance reachability check failed" error. I am unable to access the instance without rebooting it. The only relevant log entry I found is:
enX0: Could not set DHCPv4 address: Connection timed out
enX0: Failed

Additionally, our EC2 instance runs a scraping script.
